# Message to a handler in dead thread

Tags: android, warnings, intentservice

I have an IntentService that is fired at every 30 seconds by an alarm...
The first alarm is set by the user. When the broadcast receives the first alarm it calls the IntentService and the IntentService launches another alarm that will fire in 30 seconds.
But it always give's me lots of this in logcat:

```
10-08 14:32:43.433: W/MessageQueue(23819): Handler{40568030} sending message to a Handler on a dead thread
10-08 14:32:43.433: W/MessageQueue(23819): java.lang.RuntimeException: Handler{40568030} sending message to a Handler on a dead thread
10-08 14:32:43.433: W/MessageQueue(23819):  at android.os.MessageQueue.enqueueMessage(MessageQueue.java:196)
10-08 14:32:43.433: W/MessageQueue(23819):  at android.os.Handler.sendMessageAtTime(Handler.java:457)
10-08 14:32:43.433: W/MessageQueue(23819):  at android.os.Handler.sendMessageDelayed(Handler.java:430)
10-08 14:32:43.433: W/MessageQueue(23819):  at android.os.Handler.sendMessage(Handler.java:367)
10-08 14:32:43.433: W/MessageQueue(23819):  at android.location.LocationManager$ListenerTransport.onLocationChanged(LocationManager.java:193)
10-08 14:32:43.433: W/MessageQueue(23819):  at android.location.ILocationListener$Stub.onTransact(ILocationListener.java:58)
10-08 14:32:43.433: W/MessageQueue(23819):  at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:336)
10-08 14:32:43.433: W/MessageQueue(23819):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.run(Native Method)
```

this is my IntentService:

```
public class ServiceGPS extends IntentService{

    static String APP = "ACORDENOPONTO";

    private static volatile PowerManager.WakeLock lockStatic=null;

    synchronized private static PowerManager.WakeLock getLock(Context context) {
        if (lockStatic == null) {
            PowerManager mgr=
            (PowerManager)context.getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);

            lockStatic=mgr.newWakeLock(PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK, APP);
            lockStatic.setReferenceCounted(true);
        }

        return(lockStatic);
     }

    public ServiceGPS() {
        super("ServiceGPS");

    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {

        PowerManager.WakeLock lock=getLock(this.getApplicationContext());

        if (!lock.isHeld() || (flags & START_FLAG_REDELIVERY) != 0){
            lock.acquire();
        }

        super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
        return(START_REDELIVER_INTENT);

    }

    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {

        params.getCharSequence("tickerText")
        NotificationManager.criaNotification(this, params.getCharSequence("tickerText")
                                                 , params.getCharSequence("title")
                                                 , params.getCharSequence("message")
                                                 , params.getInt("id")
                                                 , (30));
        }

        PowerManager.WakeLock lock=getLock(this.getApplicationContext());

        if(lock.isHeld()){
            lock.release();
        }

        MonitoraGPS.completeWakefulIntent(intent);
    }

    public void tocaAlarmeVibraTudo(Context context){
        Intent intent = new Intent(context, TelaDespertou.class);
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        context.startActivity(intent);
    }
```

Adding NotificationManager code:

```
public class NotificationManager{
    static AlarmManager alarme;

    public static void criaNotification(Context context, CharSequence tickerText, CharSequence title,
            CharSequence message, int id, float segundos){

        alarme = (AlarmManager)context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);

        Intent abreMonitora = new Intent("MONITORAR");

        Bundle params = new Bundle();

        params.putCharSequence("tickerText", tickerText);
        params.putCharSequence("title", title);
        params.putCharSequence("message", message);
        params.putInt("id", id);

        abreMonitora.putExtras(params);

        PendingIntent vaiFazer = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, id, abreMonitora, 
                                                        PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);

        long minute = minuteToMilli(segundos);

        alarme.set( AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,
                System.currentTimeMillis() + minute,
                vaiFazer);

        Log.d("setou", "alarme" + segundos);

        NotificationUtil.criaNotification(context, tickerText, title, message, id, intent);

    }

    public static long minuteToMilli(float minute){
        long quaseMilli = (long) (minute * 1000);
        return quaseMilli;
    }

    public static void cancelaAlarme(Context context, int id){
        alarme = (AlarmManager)context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        PendingIntent operation = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, id,
                                                         new Intent("MONITORAR"),
                                                         PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);
        alarme.cancel(operation);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several things to consider here that can help you get rid of your errors and get a cleaner code:

- The alarm should be scheduled using the AlarmManager
- The ServiceGps could be launched by a WakefulBroadcastReceiver, so you don't have to handle wake lock yourself.
- If the target is below 19, you could benefit from using *setRepeating...* method in the AlarmManager.

** Don't forget the permissions in your Manifest.

Hope it helps.

Comment: the repeating is not always the same... the "NotificationManager" there is just the name of the class, because it handles the alarms and send notifications to the user... yes, i'm launching this from an WakefulBroadcastReceiver...

Comment: I assume your *NotificationManager* is customized because of the method call. Can you post that code?

Comment: Are you using some GPS listener that doesn't gets unregistered?

Comment: maybe... i'm taking the GPS current coordinates in the receiver, do i have to use `removeUpdates(this)` after getting the coordinates?

Comment: The receiver will be destroyed after it's work is done (probably after finishing *onReceive(...)* ). It's not a good practice to register for location updates there. You can create a Service and register a receiver over there, so you can always get location updates. You can shared that data through preferences, intent or binding to your service (i'd recommend the first one).

Comment: I'll include the location update in the IntentService... By the way, you're right, it was the gps... I ran that `removeUpdates(this)` method of the `LocationManager` and the messages stopped... Thank you a lot!